# Codeigniter: Update multiple Rows in Codeigniter in one statement

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I am having dictionary as

```html
array(
  'ID1' => 1 ,
  'ID2' => 2,
  'Status' => 'Done'
)
```

While I have only 2 columns in my table, ID and Status. I want to update two rows having IDs 1, and 2, using only one time ($this->db->update). Is it possible or should I have to make custom query.
I want to do like ($this->db->update(where ID1 == 1 && ID2 == 2)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Either**

```
// Get your status 
$item = array( 'Status' => $response['Status'] );

// unset status
unset($response['Status']);

// I assume except status rest all values are ids so
// array_values gives id
$this->db->where_in('id', array_values($response));

// Update table
$this->db->update('table', $item );
```

**OR**

You have to modify your array

```
    $data = array(
       array(
         'id' => 1 ,
         'Status' => 'Done'
       ),
       array(
         'id' => 2 ,
         'Status' => 'Done'
       )
    );
```

and then

```
    $this->db->update_batch('table_name', $data, 'id');
```

**Like this you can modify**

( for comment : Dear I cant do so, because I am getting response from some service. And I am not able to edit this response. )

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat test.php
<?php
$response = array(
  'ID1' => 1 ,
  'ID2' => 2,
  'Status' => 'Done'
);

$data = array(); 
$item = array( 'Status' => $response['Status'] );
unset($response['Status']);

foreach($response as $new){
        $item['id'] = $new;
        $data[] = $item; 
}
print_r($data);

// Here you update 
// $this->db->update_batch('table_name', $data, 'id');
?>
```

***Output***

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ php test.php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Status] => Done
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Status] => Done
            [id] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Dear I cant do so, because I am getting response from some service. And I am not able to edit this response.

Comment: @user6159419 please see my edit, from this you can start

Answer (score 0):

```
//this will update the values where ids equal any value in the second were_in parameter

//data is array of values to update 
$data = [
   'Status'=>'some status',
];

//array of ids to update
$ids = [1,2];

$this->db->where_in('id', $ids)->update('table_name', $data);
```